# Using R, how does one extract multiple URLs/pattern matches from a string in a dataset, and then place each URL in its own adjacent column?

Tags: r, regex

I have a (large) dataset that initially consists of an identifier and associated text (in raw HTML). Oftentimes the text will include one or more embedded links. Here's a sample dataset:

```
id text
1  <p>I love dogs!</p>
2  <p>My <strong>favorite</strong> dog is <a href="www.doge.com">this kind</a>.</p>
3  <p>I've had both <a href="labs.com">Labs</a> and <a href="http://www.huskies.com">Huskies</a> in my life.</p>
```

What I'd like as output (with the `text` column included in the same spot, but I removed it for visibility here) is:

```
id link1     link2
1        
2  doge.com
3  labs.com  huskies.com
```

I've tried using `str_extract_all()` paired with `<a\s+(?:[^>]*?\s+)?href=(["'])(.*?)\1`, but even when I double escape the backslashes I either get an "unexpected" error OR it keeps asking me for more and I have to Escape out. I feel like this method is the one I want and SHOULD work, but I can't seem to get the regex to play nicely. Here are my results so far:

```
> str_extract_all(text, "<a\s+(?:[^>]*?\s+)?href=(["'])(.*?)\1")
Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""<a\s"
> str_extract_all(text, perl(<a\s+(?:[^>]*?\s+)?href=(["'])(.*?)\1))
Error: unexpected '<' in "str_extract_all(text, perl(<"
> str_extract_all(text, "<a\\s+(?:[^>]*?\\s+)?href=(["'])(.*?)\\1")
+ 

> str_extract_all(text, perl(<a\\s+(?:[^>]*?\\s+)?href=(["'])(.*?)\\1))
Error: unexpected '<' in "str_extract_all(text, perl(<"
```

I've also tried `parseURI` from the `XML` package and for whatever reason it crashes my R session.

The other solutions I've found to date either only deal with single links, or return items in a list or vector altogether. I want to keep things separated by their identifier and in a dataset.

If needed, I could tolerate generating a separate dataset and merging them together, but there will be cases where there are no links, so I'd want to avoid any pitfalls of rows being deleted due to not having a value in any of the `link` columns.

Comment: You need to escape the backslashes and quotations e.g. `\\s+` and `\"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R does not like quotes within strings so in your example above R is considering the string ongoing:

```
str_extract_all(text, "<a\\s+(?:[^>]*?\\s+)?href=(["'])(.*?)\\1")
```

R is still looking for the end of the string since it was not escaped in the regex. R has special cases in which as single `\` can be used for escaping, (e.g `\n` for new line), see [this](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/74603_76cd14d5983f47408fdf0b323550b846.html). `\'` escapes a single quote and `\"` escapes a double quote in R regex:

```
str_extract_all(text, "<a\\s+(?:[^>]*?\\s+)?href=([\"])(.*?)\\1", text, perl=T)
```

> "\ itself is a special character that needs escape, e.g. \\d. Do not
>   confuse these regular expressions with R escape sequences such as 
>   \t."

or in your case `\"`

Comment: Ah, thank you! I knew it'd be a stupid mistake on my part. I just had to remove the `, text, perl=T` from the end and it worked perfectly!